# How can I call one helper_method from text area using ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anybody help me to resolve my small issue ? I want to call one method from text area using ROR which is defined inside application_controller.rb file as helper_method. My text area line in HTML is given below please convert it to text area tag using ROR.

Text area tag in HTML:

```
<textarea id="text" style="width:400px; height:120px" placeholder="Type your comment here" <%= person_logged_in? ? '' : 'disabled' %> ></textarea>
```

My applicatio_controller.rb file is as follows.:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :current_person, :person_logged_in?

def authenticate_user!
  redirect_to persons_login_path, alert: 'Please login to continue.' unless person_logged_in? 
end

def current_person
  @current_person ||= Person.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end

def person_logged_in?
  !!current_person
end
end
```

Please help me to convert the above text area tag in HTML to ROR.

Comment: Can you please explain the issue you're facing?

Comment: No issue Surya I just want to convert this line "<textarea id="text" style="width:400px; height:120px" placeholder="Type your comment here" <%= person_logged_in? ? '' : 'disabled' %> ></textarea>" to form_for helper using ROR.Please if you have any solution then share with me because i am new to ROR.

Comment: Ok..Surya let me to write here.
<%= form_for :person,:url => {:action => "createpost"} do |f| %>
<div class="navigation">
 <%= f.text_area :body,:width => "400px",:height => "120px",placeholder:"Type your comment here" %>
</div>
<%= f.submit  "Comment",:class => "btn-div" %>
<% end %>
Actually i want to add this line only " person_logged_in? ? '' : 'disabled' " in that text area so How can I do that .?

Comment: you should added helper method in helpers not in controllers

Comment: @Subhra_agent : It's worth nothing that you add that code in your question instead of a comment. It'd be helpful to understand and read your question's statement properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<%= f.text_area :body,:width => "400px",:height => "120px",placeholder:"Type your comment here", :disabled => @current_person  ? 'disabled' : nil %>
```